# read files from unix in batch of certain length

Tags: shell, unix

I have one file named as p.txt. 
It contains following values:

```
201601
201602
201603
201604
201605
201606
201607
201608
201609
201610
```

I want to read this records in batch of 3. i.e. 
one variable will have following three values

```
201601
201602
201603
```

in first iteration. in second iteration it will have next three lines

```
201604
201605
201606
```

If number is not fully divided by 3 then iteration will be divider +1.

how is it possible in unix?

What I have tried so far:

```
PERD=`cat P.txt`

for perd in `cat PERD_ID.txt`; 
do
    bteq << EOF
    .logon ${conn_string};

    /* Database*/
    DATABASE $ET;

    /* Update NULL LOCL_SEGMNT3_IDNs*/
    INSERT INTO T 
    SELECT  *
    FROM A
    WHERE PERIOD IN ($PERD); 

    .if errorcode != 0 then .exit 5.1;

    .LOGOFF
    .EXIT
EOF

done
```

Current code reads every line and executes insert in DB. I want to have these query for 3 period for better performance.

```
/* Update NULL LOCL_SEGMNT3_IDNs*/
INSERT INTO T 
SELECT  *
FROM A
WHERE PERIOD IN (201601,201602,201603);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to start with this simple code. Modify it at your will:

```
cat p.txt | while read a; 
do
   read b;
   read c;
   echo $a $b $c;
done
```

The variables a, b, c have the 3 values.

Comment: it is working fine when it completely divisible by 3. however if it is not it is giving me (201601,,) which is failing.

Comment: You wanted to process the lines in groups of 3. If there are only 2 or 1  items in the last group, the process it in the way you want. You can use e.g. "if" statement.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` does not have any straight forward tools/routines to read `n` lines at a time. So a combination of `xargs` with reading 3 lines using the option (`-L`) and using while-loop over `read` command, something like:

```
# 'count' a local counter variable, incremented in while-loop
# 'file' is sample input file 

$  count=1; xargs -L 3 <file | while read line; do printf "Iteration-->%d\n%s\n" "$(( count++ ))" "${line// /$'\n'}"; done
```

And it produces an output as

```
Iteration-->1
201601
201602
201603
Iteration-->2
201604
201605
201606
Iteration-->3
201607
201608
201609
Iteration-->4
201610
```

You can optimize my solution to store the every 3 line output to a variable or an array.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the mapfile / readarray bash method could fit.

Examples:

```
mapfile -n3 varA<file;echo ${varA[@]} # Get the first three lines from file and store them in a array called varA.
mapfile -s3 -n3 varB<file;echo ${varB[@]} # Skip 3 - get next three lines and store it in another array varB
mapfile -s6 -n3 varC<file;echo ${varC[@]} # Skip 6 - get next three lines, and store it in another array varC
```

Meaning that by manipulating the -s option you can achieve what you need.

Also keep in mind the following commands:

```
mapfile var<file # This fills an array called var with all the lines of file. var[0] is the first line, var[1] is the second line, etc
echo ${var[@]} # Prints the whole array
echo ${var[2]} # Prints a particular array item
echo ${#var[@]} #Prints the number of elements in array = number of lines read
```

Arrays in bash start counting from zero.
You can force mapfile to map an array by starting from 1 by using -O1 option:

```
mapfile -O1 var<file
```

PS: Actually the -O1 assigns the first array value / first file line to both var[0] and var[1] positions. Thus you will be able to refer to line 1-2-3 of  array as var[1]-var[2]-var[3] instead of the default var[0]-var[1]-var[2]

G.V